# How do I list commands shadowed by other commands in PATH?

Tags: command-line, path

How do I list *all* the commands in my path which are shadowed by other commands?

E.g., if I have `/bin/foo`, `/bin/bar`, `/usr/local/bar` and `/usr/bin/foo`, I want to see something like

```
foo in /bin shadows /usr/bin
bar in /bin shadows /usr/local/bin
```

I guess I can throw together something based on `ls` and `comm`, but I would much prefer something out of the box, especially `bash`-based (it would also be nice if aliases and functions were searched too, but that is not too important).

Comment: Id specify whether or not you want to see if aliases or functions shadow commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point or to get the answer when you know the commands you want to check.

The `which` command is used to show the full path of shell commands. The `-a` or `-all` switch will list all matches, not just the first.

```
which --all foo
```

For all commands in your path there is a small utility from PerlMonks: [Pathfinder - find duplicate (shadowed) programs in your PATH](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=29787)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @path = split /:/, $ENV{PATH};
my %path_inodes;
my @clean_path;

for (@path) {
  next unless m#^/#;
  my ($dev,$ino) = stat;
  next unless defined $dev;
  my $key = "$dev $ino";
  if (exists $path_inodes{$key}) {
    print "warning: $_ is linked to $path_inodes{$key}\n";
    next;
  }
  $path_inodes{$key} = $_;
  push @clean_path, $_;
}

my %progs;

## print "clean path is @clean_path\n";

for my $dir (@clean_path) {
  use DirHandle;
  my @files =
    sort grep !/^\.\.?$/,
    DirHandle->new($dir)->read;
  ## print "$dir: @files\n";
  for my $file (@files) {
    if (exists $progs{$file}) {
      print "$file in $dir is shadowed by $progs{$file}\n";
      next;
    }
    $progs{$file} = $dir;
  }
}
```